# GeckoWebbrowser click class name in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

i want to click Class element.
i found c# code but couldn't found vb.net code so i changed to vb.net.

but i can't convert one of code.

this is c# code what i found

```
foreach (GeckoElement currentTag in tagsCollection)
{
   if (currentTag.GetAttribute("class").Equals("class_name"))
    {
         ((GeckoHtmlElement)currentTag).Click()
    }
    //delay some seconds to click next button...
}
```

and i converted to vb.net but i couldn't convert one of c# code to vb.net.

i want to convert this code ((GeckoHtmlElement)currentTag).Click() to vb.net

```
     Dim tagCollection As GeckoElementCollection = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
            For Each currettag As GeckoElement In GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
                If currettag.GetAttribute("class") = "classname1" Then
                    currettag.???? // i can't convert ((GeckoHtmlElement)currentTag).Click() to vb.net code
                End If
            Next
```

thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CType(currettag,GeckoHtmlElement).Click
```

Comment: When you answer a technical question, you need to describe how you got your answer. In particular, how does your answer differ from what the original poster showed.

Comment: Hi Bob, there is nothing to describe in this case